# Sending files/deirectories from a local Unix machine to a remote Unix server

Tags: linux, scp, remote, shared-folders

How do I send files or directories to my school's remote server from my Ubuntu desktop? I have tried everything from YouTube, and everything keeps on giving me a lost connection when I try to run the command.

This is the command I tried:

```
scp filename username@ipaddress:/users/students/username
```

Comment: `scp -vvv filename...` will show you more information about the problem. Can you add this output to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Rsync in Terminal. Rsync is a program similar to scp, providing syncrosization over the network. You can sync folders and files to a remote computer with the template below.

```
rsync -a ~/filedir user@remote_host:destination_dir
```

If you type this command, you will "push" the files to the opposite server.

If you want to "pull" from the host server, you can use the command below:

```
rsync -a user@remote_host:/dest_dir local_dir
```

With the SSH services of the target and source machines active, Rsync must be installed on both machines.

You can find more information about rsync on its [manual page.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)